# Vue.js - Typescript: Expected method shorthand in object literal

Tags: typescript, vue.js

inside my input component, I have this code in order to make the v-model on the input works as a component:

```
computed: {
inputListeners: function() {
  const vm = this;
  return Object.assign({},
    this.$listeners,
    {
      input: (event: any) => {
        vm.$emit('input', event.target.value);
      },
    },
  );
},
```

This is the official example:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components

Now Typescript return me this Warning:

```
WARNING in /Users/../components/InputText.vue
Expected method shorthand in object literal ('{inputListeners() {...}}').
> inputListeners: function() {
```

Do you know the code solution?

Comment: This is just a linter warning; you can rewrite the object as suggested: `inputListeners() {` instead of what you have (`inputListeners: function () {`

Comment: I did it -- inputListeners(this) { -- and it fixed the warning. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Use method shorthand format: `inputListeners() { ... }`

```js
computed: {
  inputListeners() {
    ...
  }
}
```